# Help with recreation of table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to recreate the following table in LaTeX:

[image]

I'm still fairly new to the language and have the feeling that I'm not going to get very far with my current attempt:

```
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
   \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Blechdicke & d & Voraussetzungen\\\cline{2-2}
    s & \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
            2,4 & 3,2 & 4,0 & 4,8 & 5,6 \\
        \end{tabular}
        & für die\\\cline{2-2}
    & \specialcell{\scriptsize Bruchlasten in N/Niet für einschnittige\\\scriptsize Einzel-u.Reihenvernietung} & Berechnung\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

There already are several issues:

1) The numbers in the second row aren't aligned horizontally and the cells don't have the same width.

2) Writing the text in the top right cell of the image split over several rows looks off.

3) I can't think of a way to integrate the block of numbers in the center of the image with the table I set up in the provide snippet.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need the `multirow` package for the vertical spans (or use empty cells), `\cline` statements, `\multicolumn` etc. But you should ask yourself a question: Do you really want to produce this table layout? Do you want to read such a table? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestions, I'll look into that package. And yes, I do require exactly that layout as there are different sections that are associated with different cases (this is a rivet table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt. Not exactly the same layout, but I think it's cleaner and still has all the same information:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[tbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}} \toprule
Blechdicke *) & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$d$} & \multirow{3}{*}{Berechnung **)}\\
$s$ & 2.4 & 3.2 & 4.0 & 4.8 & 5.6 \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Bruchlasten} \\ \midrule
0.8 & 1240 & 1640 & 2040 & 2440 & & \multirow{13}{*}{**), $\frac{d}{s} \leq 5.5$, $\frac{e}{d} \geq 2.0$} \\
1.0 & 1540 & 2050 & 2550 & 3060 \\
1.2 & 1630 & 2460 & 3060 & 3670 & 4270 \\
1.4 & 1710 & 2740 & 3570 & 4280 & 4980 \\
1.5 & \multirow{9}{*}{1971} & 2800 & 3830 & 4580 & 5340 \\
1.6 & & 2880 & 4080 & 4890 & 5700 \\
1.8 & & 3020 & 4320 & 5460 & 6400 \\
2.0 & & \multirow{6}{*}{3152} & 4460 & 5660 & 7120 \\
2.5 & & & 4850 & 6200 & 7950 \\
3.0 & & & \multirow{4}{*}{4895} & \multirow{4}{*}{6466} & 8500 \\
3.2 & & & & & \multirow{3}{*}{8775} \\
4.0 \\
5.0 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{p{0.75in}}{Scherkraft in N/Niet} & 1791 & 3152 & 4895 & 6466 & 8775 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{p{0.75in}}{Kopfzug-Bruchkraft in N/Niet} & 1112 & 1668 & 2958 & 4270 & 5665 & ***) \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your table looks really good! I'll make some slight adjustments, but it's pretty much more than I could've asked for.